# Mysql2::Error: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction: SELECT `rpush_notifications`.`id` FROM `rpush_notifications`

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
[ERROR] ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid, Mysql2::Error: Lock wait timeout exceeded; 
try restarting transaction: SELECT  `rpush_notifications`.`id` FROM `rpush_notifications` 
WHERE (processing = 0 AND delivered = 0 AND failed = 0 AND (deliver_after IS NULL OR deliver_after < '2019-07-03 14:27:05.462072'))  
ORDER BY deliver_after ASC, created_at ASC LIMIT 100 FOR UPDATE
```

Rpush gem version 3.3.1

My configuration:config/initializers/rpush.rb

Rpush gem version 3.3.1

My configuration:config/initializers/rpush.rb

```
Rpush.configure do |config|
config.client = :active_record
config.push_poll = 2
config.batch_size = 100
config.pid_file = 'tmp/pids/rpush.pid'
config.log_file = 'log/rpush.log'

config.log_level = (defined?(Rails) && Rails.logger) ? 
Rails.logger.level : ::Logger::Severity::INFO


end

Rpush.reflect do |on|


on.notification_delivered do |notification|
# notification.destroy
end

on.gcm_canonical_id do |old_id, canonical_id|
device = DeviceInfo.find_by_device_token(old_id)
device.device_token = canonical_id if device
device.save! if device
end

on.gcm_invalid_registration_id do |app, error, registration_id|
devices = DeviceInfo.where('device_token = ?', registration_id)
devices.each do |device|
if !device.uninstalled_flag
device.uninstalled_flag = true
device.uninstalled_at = Time.now
device.save
end
end
end
end


devices.androids.find_in_batches do |devices_batch|
tokens = devices_batch.map(&:device_token)
n = Rpush::Gcm::Notification.new
n.app = android_app
n.registration_ids = tokens
n.expiry = expiry
n.data = {'message' => @description, 'page' => @onclick_page, 'page_id' => 1, 'title' => @title, 'image_url' => @image_url}
n.priority = 'high'        # Optional, can be either 'normal' or 'high'
n.content_available = true
n.save!
end
```

Comment: This does not look like a question. Also, what have you tried? A lot can go wrong in running queries on the DB. Did you try to run the same SQL in a SQL console? Did you try to SELECT ... For UPDATE a single row with your code? Does this happen all the time? Is error this intermittent?

Comment: I have tried this link https://github.com/rpush/rpush/issues/200 "(How to reproduce this bug in your localhost. (run it in rails c)") to reproduce in my local but not able to replicate it. It only occur in production environment.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have transaction clash between this query and another one on the affected table rows. In a concurrent setting `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` is a bad idea, it will keep the transaction running for longer.

- Check transaction isolation on the DB and what level is required for application to work properly.
- Look for the other transaction that holds the lock when this error happens and see why it keeps the transaction lock for too long.
- Check if the `FOR UPDATE` part is really required and if the code can be refactored to not use `FOR UPDATE`.
- Maybe you can add another lock, either in the application or the DB to manage the synchronization of these competing transactions.